# How to extract max value from vector and position it occurs in R?

Tags: r, vector

In a vector in R, how do you obtain the position where the maximum value occurs?

```r
V[i] <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
max(V)
# [1] 7
```

How do I get the position that the max value occurs in the vector? In this case, the output would be 7 because V[7]=7

Comment: use which.max()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get all the maximum value indexes in a R vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26693693/get-all-the-maximum-value-indexes-in-a-r-vector)

Comment: In case you have more than 1 maximum: `which(max(x) == x)`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
V <- c(1,2,3,7,5,6,4)

needle <- max(V)

position <- match(needle, V)

V[position] # returns 7
```

Comment: V[position] returns 7, "position" however is 4